# Group by multiple columns, agregate others and select all in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, group-by, aggregate

I am using SQL server and I can't seem to construct the query I want.  I have a table with several columns, among them are

PARAMETER_NAME, GW_LOCATION_ID, Report_Result, DETECT_FLAG

I want a query to return

1. a row for each unique Parameter-Location combination
2. the maximum value of the **Report_Result** column for that unique Parameter-Location combination and
3. the **DETECT_FLAG** value associated with the maximum value.

There are other columns in addition to **DETECT_FLAG** that I want to return but I think that if I can get this part worked out, I should be able to return the other columns similarly.

The query works if I group by **PARAMETER_NAME** and **GW_LOCATION_ID** and aggregate the **Report_Result** column (see below).  However, when I add the **DETECT_FLAG** column, I get the error, "*Column 'SLVs_Flagged.DETECT_FLAG' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*"  What I want is the value of DETECT_FLAG for the row returned by MAX(**Report_Result**).

```
SELECT 
PARAMETER_NAME, GW_LOCATION_ID, MAX(Report_Result)
FROM SLVs_Flagged
GROUP BY PARAMETER_NAME, GW_LOCATION_ID
ORDER BY PARAMETER_NAME, GW_LOCATION_ID;
```

I have tried to do a subselect to return the **DETECT_FLAG** value that corresponds to MAX(**Report_Result**) but I try to use a WHERE condition and I get another error.  Please advise how I can execute this query.

Here is a subset of the data for testing.

```
PARAMETER_NAME  GW_LOCATION_ID  Report_Result   DETECT_FLAG
Perchlorate CDBO-6  2.38    N
Perchlorate CDBO-6  1.45    N
Perchlorate CDV-16-02655    4   N
Perchlorate CDV-16-02655    0.537   Y
Perchlorate CDV-16-02655    4   N
Perchlorate CDV-16-02656    100 N
Perchlorate CDV-16-02656    0.394   Y
Perchlorate CDV-16-02656    4   N
Perchlorate CDV-16-02656    4   N
Perchlorate CDV-16-02657    4   N
Perchlorate CDV-16-02657    4   N
Perchlorate CDV-16-02657    4   N
Perchlorate CDV-16-02657    0.174   Y
Perchlorate CDV-16-02658    4   N
Perchlorate CDV-16-02658    4   Y
Perchlorate CDV-16-02658    0.126   Y
Perchlorate CDV-16-02658    0.0561  Y
Perchlorate CDV-16-02658    20  N
Perchlorate CDV-16-02658    4   N
Perchlorate CDV-16-02659    4   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen R-16 S4 0.003   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen R-20 S1 0.003   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen R-20 S1 0.003   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen R-20 S1 0.003   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen R-20 S2 0.003   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen R-20 S2 0.003   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen R-20 S3 0.003   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen R-20 S3 0.003   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen R-20 S3 0.003   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen R-27    0.003   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen R-31 S2 0.003   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen R-32 S3 0.003   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen R-32 S3 0.003   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 1A    0.01    N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 1A    -0.01   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 2 0.04    N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 2 0.01    N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 2A    0   N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 3 0.04    N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 3 0.04    N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 4 0.04    N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 4 0.04    N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 4 0.04    N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 4 0.04    N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 4 0.04    N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 4 0.04    N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 4 0.04    N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 8 0.04    N
Nitrate as Nitrogen Test Well 8 0.04    N
```

Comment: And what if there are two rows with same max Report_Result value?

Comment: I just need one of them.  Maybe I can set a condition to choose one of them based on criteria from another column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `greatest-n-per-group` problem and there are many ways to solve it (`CROSS APPLY`, window functions, subquery with `GROUP BY`, etc). Here's a method using window functions and a CTE:

```
WITH ct AS
  ( SELECT *,
           rn = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PARAMETER_NAME, GW_LOCATION_ID
                             ORDER BY Report_Result DESC)
    FROM SLVs_Flagged
  )
SELECT PARAMETER_NAME, GW_LOCATION_ID, 
       Max_Report_Result = Report_Result,
       DETECT_FLAG
       -- more columns
FROM ct
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY PARAMETER_NAME, GW_LOCATION_ID ;
```

The query will return all tied results (if there are ties). If you want a single result for every `(PARAMETER_NAME, GW_LOCATION_ID)` combination, you can resolve ties by using `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()` and modifying the `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER (..)` clause. Eg. (prefer `DETECT_FLAG` with `N` over `Y`):

```
           rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PARAMETER_NAME, GW_LOCATION_ID
                                   ORDER BY Report_Result DESC, DETECT_FLAG)
```

Comment: That seems to work very well @ypercube. Thank you!  Do you have a good reference or tutorial that you can point out so I can understand how to use these concepts better?  In particular, I do not understand RANK, PARTITION or the ct part very well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query is more intuitive to understand:

```
create table SLVs_Flagged (PARAMETER_NAME varchar(30), GW_LOCATION_ID varchar(30), Report_Result int, DETECT_FLAG char(1) )
go
insert into dbo.SLVs_Flagged 
values ('abc', 'cor1', 128, 'N'), ('abc', 'cor1', 12, 'Y')
, ('def', 'cor1', 500, 'Y'), ('def', 'cor1', 50, 'N')
go

;with s as (
select max(Report_Result) as Report_Result, PARAMETER_NAME,  GW_LOCATION_ID
from SLVs_Flagged 
group by PARAMETER_NAME, GW_LOCATION_ID)
SELECT s.Report_Result, s.PARAMETER_NAME,  s.GW_LOCATION_ID, t.DETECT_FLAG
FROM SLVs_Flagged t
inner join s 
on t.PARAMETER_NAME = s.PARAMETER_NAME and t.GW_LOCATION_ID = s.GW_LOCATION_ID and t.Report_Result = s.Report_Result
```

Comment: You need to alias the columns in SELECT and GROUP BY in the main query. Because `s` and `T` have columns with the same name.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, yes, you are right. Just fixed it. Thx

Comment: Reading this again, I don't see how it would work. The `GROUP BY` would forbid the `t`  columns to appear in the SELECT list. Have you tried this? GROUP BY is done after the CROSS APPLY but your code suggests you are trying to do the GROUP BY before the CROSS APPLY. I suggest you use a derived table, to do the GROUP BY first.

Comment: My bad. "Cross apply" does not work here. Re-write the answer with runnable test case. Thx @ypercubeᵀᴹ